# Pressure rise in a container as small amount of liquid is vaporized

Tags: thermodynamics, gas, evaporation

How would one calculate pressure rise in some closed volume as small amount of liquid is added to it? Volume is initially in vacuum. Amount of liquid is not enough to get volume saturated. Let's say 1 g of water in 1m^3 tank and temperature is 50C. What would happen if one changes water to some other liquid, for example NH3? Would pressure be different? How accurate would calculations be? Real gases are not ideal so I would assume there is some inaccuracy

Thanks,

DrMushroom

Comment: For the conditions you stated, the ideal gas law should be good enough, as that is a VERY small amount of liquid in a very large vapor volume at a relatively high temperature.